# How to read large file into R environment

Tags: r, hpc

I have a 14.8GB file I am trying to read into R within a HPC.

Currently I set up an environment with 30GB of memory to try to read this file, but trying to use `fread()` produces a bus error:

```
library(data.table)
df <- fread('file.txt')

#After reading file I plan to condense all the columns by a Gene column:
setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, paste, collapse = ", "), by = Genes]
```

Am I wrong in using `data.table` and `fread` to try to read in such a large file - is there another R package I can use or something else I should try?

Comment: Try the vroom package.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the HPC part, but I suggest to create a Sqlite database from the file, e.g. by [sqldf::read.csv.sql](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sqldf/versions/0.4-11/topics/read.csv.sql).

The next step then would be to condense to columns using the proper SQL statement.

Comment: Thank you for this I'll check it out!